# Python: Reversing string/list using reduce

Tags: python, string, functional-programming

I'm asked to reverse a string using the `reduce` method of `functools`. My first attempts were the following:

```
string = 'test_string'
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, reversed(string))
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, string[::-1])
```

They indeed reverse the string, but the solution wasn't accepted by the TA.

Now I'm wondering what other ways are there to reverse a string using `reduce`? Is there a keyword to use that can start from the opposite end?

Comment: They weren't accepted because you reverse the string *then* pass it to reduce, which just takes it apart and rebuilds it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, that's also what I suspect. But given how `reduce` works, is it even possible to reverse a list that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really using `reduce` for the right purpose here, as you're just feeding it the string reversed and then simply adding up the substrings (which isn't doing anything). Instead you're looking for something like:

```
string = 'test_string'
reduce(lambda x, y: y+x, string)
# 'gnirts_tset'
```

---

The example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) is quite illustrative of what `reduce` is doing. Take for instance:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

This calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`. Hence the left value `x` is being accumulated, and the function is being applied over both the accumulated term `x` and the next element in the iterable `y`.

So in the case of strings, by adding both terms (the accumulated and the next element) in reversed order, the result will be the input string reversed.